# Android viewpager showing last value in the index in the size of array in Android

Tags: android, json, android-viewpager

I am getting data from the http server, I am able to show the last value of json index, however, I am unable to show all the values in my json array in viewpager. Please verify my code and give me a solution.
Thanks in advance

```
package com.example.vasundharaapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
     static final int NUM_ITEMS = 8;
        AdapterTask adapter;
        ViewPager viewPager;
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        List<Channels> channelData;
        String URl="http://172.17.22.21:925/api/homepage/gethomescroll";
        JSONObject json;
        JSONArray chanlarray;
 String artimage,articaleTitle,articaleSdec,articaldec,aricaleId,articlThumImage;

       ImageView anubandam,yuvatharang,beauty,dheera,events,ghumaghumalu,glomer,sweethome,work; 
        String[] resul;
        Timer timer;
        int page = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        anubandam=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.anubandam);
        yuvatharang=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Yuva);
        beauty=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.beauty);
        dheera=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dheera);
        events=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.events);
        ghumaghumalu=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ghumagumalu);
        glomer=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.glamor);
        sweethome=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sweet);
        work=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.work);
        startProgressDialog();
        getChannels();
    beauty.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,BeautyActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }
    private void getChannels() {

         new Thread()
         {

             public void run() {
                 System.out.println("running");
                 String responce=SendRequest.GET(URl);
                 Log.d("responce", responce);
                 channelData=parseJSON(responce);
                 Message msg=new Message();
                 msg.arg1 = 1;
                 handler.sendMessage(msg);                       
             }      
         }.start();


    }
     private List<Channels> parseJSON(String responce) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
         List<Channels> chanel = new ArrayList<Channels>();
         try {
                chanlarray = new JSONArray(responce);
                for (int i = 0; i < chanlarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject channelName=chanlarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String image = channelName.getString("articlethumbimg");
                    String title = channelName.getString("articletitle");
                    String article=channelName.getString("articleshortdec");
                    //channelData.add(new Channels(image, title,article));

                }

            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }           
            return chanel;
        };



     private final Handler handler = new Handler() {

            public void handleMessage(Message msg)
            {
                stopProgressDialog();
                adapter = new AdapterTask(chanlarray,MainActivity.this);
                viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
                pageSwitcher(4);

            }

        };


    private void startProgressDialog() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    private void stopProgressDialog() {
        if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing())
            progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onResume();
}
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public void pageSwitcher(int seconds) {
        timer = new Timer(); // At this line a new Thread will be created
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new RemindTask(), 0, seconds * 1000); // delay
                                                                        // in
        // milliseconds
    }

        // this is an inner class...
    class RemindTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            // As the TimerTask run on a seprate thread from UI thread we have
            // to call runOnUiThread to do work on UI thread.
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    if (page > 8) { // In my case the number of pages are 5
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                        page=1;

                    } else {
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(page++);
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }
    class AdapterTask extends PagerAdapter{
        Context context;
        String redu[];
        JSONArray article;
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        private List<Channels> articlelist;
        AdapterTask(JSONArray article, Context context) {
            this.context = context;
            this.article = article;
            //this.content=content;
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return article.length();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
        }
        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
            ImageView imgflag;
            TextView txt,title;

            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fashionzone, container,
                    false); 
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/eenadu.ttf");
            imgflag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flag);
            txt=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.atext);
            title=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.atitle);


            for (int j = 0; j < chanlarray.length(); j++) {

                try {
                    JSONObject channelName = chanlarray.getJSONObject(j);
                    aricaleId=channelName.getString("articleId");
                    articaleTitle=channelName.getString("articletitle");
                    articaleSdec=channelName.getString("articleshortdec");
                    artimage=channelName.getString("articleimage");
                    articlThumImage=channelName.getString("articlethumbimg");
                    articaldec=channelName.getString("articledec"); 
                    title.setTypeface(tf);
                    txt.setTypeface(tf);
                    title.setText(articaleTitle);   
                    txt.setText(articaleSdec);
                    try{
                        Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(articlThumImage).into(imgflag);
                        }catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                } catch (JSONException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

}

            ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);
            imgflag.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,DetailsActivity.class);
                    //Bitmap bmp = flag[position];
                    i.putExtra("image", artimage);
                    i.putExtra("txt",articaldec );
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });

            txt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {              
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,DetailsActivity.class);
                    //Bitmap bmp = flag[position];
                    i.putExtra("image", artimage);
                    i.putExtra("txt",articaldec );
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });

            return itemView;
        }
          @Override
            public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
                 ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
            }


    }

    public class Channels {

        private String image;
        private String title;
        private String desc;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly suggest you to avoid parsing the json into `instantiateItem`. The `Adapter` should receive a `Collection` of items, usually referred like dataset, and from that inflating the views. This way you have to pay the parsing time, delaying the drawing of your views. To fix your issue you have to remove the for loop from `instantiateItem`. `instantiateItem` is called `getCount` times, and you have to use the parameter position to get the item to represent from your json. Replace the for loop with

```
JSONObject channelName = article.getJSONObject(positon);
```

Comment: thank you its working fine.. but through intent i send that  particular articles to another activity. when i click on one article its showing another article in the that activity my code is like this

Comment: ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);
   imgflag.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,DetailsActivity.class);
     //Bitmap bmp = flag[position];
     i.putExtra("image", artimage);
     i.putExtra("txt",articaldec );
     startActivity(i);
    }
   });
   
   
   return itemView;